# How do I find an HTML anchor control in telerik:radgrid? 

Tags: asp.net, telerik

How do I find an HTML anchor control in telerik:radgrid?

Answer (score 0):

Call the getElemenentsByTagName("a") js method for the grid DOM element (div) which should returns an array of all anchor elements inside the grid html table. Then you will need to identify the anchors by their text or href value.